# Adding setState inside onChanged of DrowDownSearch makes it unable to update

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
final locationKey = GlobalKey<DropdownSearchState<Location>>();
Location selectedcountry;
int selectedcountryid
DropdownSearch<Location>(
                        key: locationKey,
                        maxHeight: 400,
                        mode: Mode.MENU,
                        items: locs,
                        itemAsString: (Location? u) => u!.countryname,
                        showSearchBox: true,
                        selectedItem: selectedcountry,
                        onChanged: (Location? newValue) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedcountry = newValue!;
                            selectedcountryid = newValue.countryid;
                            tag = RemoteServices()
                                .getTags(token, selectedcountryid);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
```

The DropDown menu doesn't change the value with setState inside onChanged.
After removing setState, it works fine. But, I need setState in order to update other widget.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method to update state

```dart
void updateSelectedCountry(Location country){
 setState(() {
                            selectedcountry = newValue!;
                            selectedcountryid = newValue.countryid;
                            tag = RemoteServices()
                                .getTags(token, selectedcountryid);
                          });
}
```

And call this method in onchange by passing the country